# Integración en Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo este programa que funciona pero me gustaría que los puntos que aparecen por encima de la función aparecieran en otro color, para así diferenciar mejor por donde va la curva. Pero no sé como hacerlo, si alguien pudiera indicarme cómo hacerlo, lo agradecería!

```
curve(x^3, xlim=c(0,1),xlab="x",ylab="f(x)")
n=500 #se puede cambiar a 50000 y se acercara más a 0.25
U=matrix(runif(2*n),ncol=2) #genero 100 valores en dos columnas
points(U,col="red")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes establecer el color en función del valor `y` de cada punto y si el mismo esta sobre o debajo de la curva:

```
points(U,col=ifelse(U[,2] > U[,1]^3, "red", "blue"))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! No sabía que en la función 'points' se podía poner!